# Running baker with Docker image: "No such file or directory"

Tags: baker

Endorser and accuser work fine, but baker gets this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/tezos-baker-005-PsBabyM1 --chain main --base-dir "/var/run/te
zos/client" run with local node "/var/run/tezos/node/data" "baker"

Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
Baker started.
Fatal error:
  No such file or directory
```

I checked and `/var/run/tezos/client` and `/var/run/tezos/node/data` exist. I can't figure out what "file or directory" is the baker talking about.

Edit: I am using [this repository](https://github.com/hodl-dot-farm/tezos-on-gke/blob/master/tezos-baker/tezos-private-node-deployment.yaml#L173) to run Tezos on Kubernetes.

Comment: Show the docker command you used. Most likely you did not volume map in the existing data dir for the node or the existing client dir for finding your keys.

Comment: That is not the case. Data dir and client dir, as I stated, exist and are accessible to the container. Anyways, I edited the question adding my Kubernetes configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No such file or directory" means only one thing.  You have three possibilities: `tezos-baker-005-PsBabyM1`, `/var/run/tezos/client`, or `/var/run/tezos/node/data` When you launch the baker, `/var/run/tezos/node/data` should have the same contents as when you run the tezos-node container. Additionally, the baker must be able to see the contents of `/var/run/tezos/client` to access the signing keys. This path was created by tezos-client container.

Comment: And that's correct. Everything is fine!
In fact, if I change the alias of the baker to something else, it gives error that it can't find that specific alias. If I change the node data dir, it says that it can't find context dir.

Comment: @Babell Can you mark the answer as correct please?